# How to allow matplotlib bar chart to go beyond the border, so I have to pan to see the rest of the graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

can someone help me with this graph plot, please? I have a categorical plot with 180 categories. I want to plot them in the same bar plot. To clearly visualize the graph I want to allow the x-axis to exceed the figure size, so I will view a part of the graph and I will have to pan to view the rest. Thanks.

there is my code:

```
#Data preparation

data = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass("covid_cases")
df_temp = data.groupby("Country_Re")[["Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovred"]].max().reset_index()
df_temp.drop(df_temp[(df_temp.Confirmed == 0) & (df_temp.Recovred == 0) & (df_temp.Deaths == 0)].index, inplace=True)

#Graph plot

ind = np.arange(df_temp.Country_Re.count())

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,10))

p1 = ax.bar(ind - 0.25, df_temp.Confirmed, 0.25, color=(0.95, 0.62, 0.07, 1))
p2 = ax.bar(ind, df_temp.Recovred, 0.25, color=(0.12, 0.52, 0.29, 1))
p3 = ax.bar(ind + 0.25, df_temp.Deaths, 0.25, color=(1, 0, 0, 1))

ax1.set_title('Confirmed, Recovred and Deaths numbers by Countries.')
plt.xticks(ind, df_temp.Country_Re, rotation=90)

ax.set_yscale('symlog')
ax.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]), ('Confirmed', 'Recovred', 'Deaths'))
ax.margins(x=0.001)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, ind.max()+1, 1.0))
plt.tick_params(axis="x", width=10)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image: GraphPlot]

Comment: You can plot a very big plot and use some image viewer to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using matplotlib [slider widgets](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider). The official demo can be found at https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html.

Here is a simplier version of it:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t,s)

# xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
# Define what you see when initially plotted
plt.axis([0, 10, -1, 1])

# plt.axes(rect, projection=None, polar=False, **kwargs)
# rect is a 4-tuple of floats  = [left, bottom, width, height]
# A new axes is added with dimensions rect in normalized (0, 1) units using add_axes on the current figure.
# (left, bottom) specify lower left corner coordinates of the new axes in normalized (0, 1) units
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

# Slider(ax, label, valmin, valmax)
spos = Slider(axpos, 'Pos', 0.1, 90.0)

def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    ax.axis([pos,pos+10,-1,1])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

spos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is a bar plot example based on your code:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

df = pd.DataFrame({'[0, 1)':np.random.rand(100),
                   '[1, 2)':np.random.rand(100)+1,
                   '[2, 3)':np.random.rand(100)+2})

n = math.ceil(df['[0, 1)'].count())
ind = np.arange(df['[0, 1)'].count())[:n]

p1 = ax.bar(ind - 0.25, df['[0, 1)'], 0.25, color=(0.95, 0.62, 0.07, 1))
p2 = ax.bar(ind, df['[1, 2)'], 0.25, color=(0.12, 0.52, 0.29, 1))
p3 = ax.bar(ind + 0.25, df['[2, 3)'], 0.25, color=(1, 0, 0, 1))

# xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
# Define what you see when initially plotted
plt.axis([-1, 10, 0, 3])

# plt.axes(rect, projection=None, polar=False, **kwargs)
# rect is a 4-tuple of floats  = [left, bottom, width, height]
# A new axes is added with dimensions rect in normalized (0, 1) units using add_axes on the current figure.
# (left, bottom) specify the new axes lower left corner coordinates in normalized (0, 1) units
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

# Slider(ax, label, valmin, valmax)
spos = Slider(axpos, 'Pos', -0.2, 90.0)

def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    ax.axis([pos,pos+10,0,3])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

spos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found an adequate solution, so I plotted my graph into two subplots.

There is the code :

```
#Data preparation

data = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass("covid_cases")
df_temp = data.groupby("Country_Re")[["Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovred"]].max().reset_index()
df_temp.drop(df_temp[(df_temp.Confirmed == 0) & (df_temp.Recovred == 0) & (df_temp.Deaths == 0)].index, inplace=True)

#Graph Plot

n = math.ceil(df_temp.Country_Re.count() / 2)
ind = np.arange(df_temp.Country_Re.count())[:n]

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(20, 10), dpi=70)

p1 = ax1.bar(ind - 0.25, df_temp.Confirmed.head(n), 0.25, color=(0.95, 0.62, 0.07, 1))
p2 = ax1.bar(ind, df_temp.Recovred.head(n), 0.25, color=(0.12, 0.52, 0.29, 1))
p3 = ax1.bar(ind + 0.25, df_temp.Deaths.head(n), 0.25, color=(1, 0, 0, 1))
p4 = ax2.bar(ind - 0.25, df_temp.Confirmed.tail(n), 0.25, color=(0.95, 0.62, 0.07, 1))
p5 = ax2.bar(ind, df_temp.Recovred.tail(n), 0.25, color=(0.12, 0.52, 0.29, 1))
p6 = ax2.bar(ind + 0.25, df_temp.Deaths.tail(n), 0.25, color=(1, 0, 0, 1))

plt.sca(ax1)
ax1.set_title('Confirmed, Recovred and Deaths numbers by Country_Re.')
plt.xticks(ind, df_temp.Country_Re.head(n), rotation=90)
ax1.set_yscale('symlog')
ax1.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]), ('Confirmed', 'Recovred', 'Deaths'))
ax1.margins(x=0.001)
plt.tick_params(axis="x", width=10)
plt.tight_layout()


plt.sca(ax2)
ax2.set_title('Confirmed, Recovred and Deaths numbers by Country_Re.')
plt.xticks(ind, df_temp.Country_Re.tail(n), rotation=90)
ax2.set_yscale('symlog')
ax2.legend((p4[0], p5[0], p6[0]), ('Confirmed', 'Recovred', 'Deaths'))
ax2.margins(x=0.001)
plt.tick_params(axis="x", width=10)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

There is the result:
[image: GraphPlot]